# Why can't my code record the results of the game?

Tags: c++

I've been trying to do this program for a while now but i have a problem for some reason.
I am supposed to make a program where I have a 8*8 2D array with a mouse situated in the center of an island surrounded with by 1*1 2D array of water and a cat that is located in another fixed location (away from the mouse) The mouse is allowed to move one tile per move and can not move diagonally.
The movement is determined by a random number generator that is limited to 0,1,2 and 3 {each number represents a direction). The mouse is allowed 100 moves and then the game stops, it also stops when the mouse bumps into the cat (death), crosses a bridge that is situated in the middle of the right side(escape)or goes into water (drown) the program is supposed to run a couple of times and record the number of deaths, escapes and drowns.but I keep getting zero deaths, zero escapes and zero drowns every time i try to run the program.
here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std; 
#define N 9
#define M 9
int direction(int x, int A[M][N], int row, int col)
{
    int m;
    if (x == 0)
        m = A[row - 1][col]; //North
    if (x == 1)
        m = A[row+1][col]; //South
    if (x == 2)
        m = A[row][col - 1]; //West
    if (x == 3)
        m = A[row][col + 1]; //East
    return m;
}

int main()
{

    int v, S1, S2, S3, S4;
    int Mouse, Cat, Bridge;
    int death = 0, escape = 0, drown = 0;
    int A[M][N];
    for (int a = 0;a < 10;a++)
    {
        for (int i = 0;i < M;i++)
            S1 = A[i][0] = 4;
        for (int i = 0;i < M;i++)
            S2 = A[i][8] = 4;
        for (int j = 0;j < N;j++)
            S3 = A[0][j] = 4;
        for (int j = 0;j < N;j++)
            S4 = A[8][j] = 4;
        for (int i = 1;i < M;i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1;j < N;j++)
                A[i][j] = 0;
        }
        Mouse = A[4][4] = 1; //mouse
        Cat = A[5][2] = 2; //cat
        Bridge = A[4][8] = 3; //bridge
        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        for (int b = 0;b < 100;b++)
        {   v = rand() % 4;
            int m=direction(v, A, 4, 4);
            if (m == Cat)
            {
                death++;
                break;
            }
            else if (m == Bridge)
            {
                escape++;
                break;
            }
            else if (m == S1 || m == S2 || m == S3 || m == S4)
            {
                drown++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "The mouse died " << death << " times and escaped " << escape << " times and drowned " << drown << " times" << endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: the mouse may have chosen to stay on the island. I can understand that, as the other choices are potentially lethal.

Comment: Do you really want to end the program without printing anything when the mouse dies? If not you need to get rid of some of the `return 0;` you have in your loop.

Comment: make yourself familiar with the debugger, and step through your code. you will be able to spot and fix most of the semantic errors yourself easily. If something C++ specific remains, edit your post.

Comment: Also get `srand((unsigned)time(NULL));` out of your loop. When you have it in a loop like this it will pretty much ensure that you won't get random numbers. The reason is time did not change between calls (resolution of a second) you seed the same value and the random number generator returns the same value.

Comment: Thanks everyone, the problem i am mostly facing now is updating the mouse's location? @drescherjm

Answer (score 0):

The mouse never moves from initial location and the terrain near the mouse is safe. So nothing can happen.
Replace the cicle in the code with

```
  int x = 4,y=4;        // Mouse coords
   for (int b = 0;b < 100;b++)
    {   v = rand() % 4;
        int m=direction(v, A, x, y);
        if (m == Cat)
        {
            death++;
            break;
        }
        else if (m == Bridge)
        {
            escape++;
            break;
        }
        else if (m == S1 || m == S2 || m == S3 || m == S4)
        {
            drown++;
            break;
        }
        // Nothing happened, move the mouse
        A[x][y] = 0;         // Clear the actual mouse location
        if(v==0) x--;
        if(v==1) x++;
        if(v==2) y--;
        if(v==4) y++;
        A[x][y] = 1;        // Mark the mouse on the map

    }
```

Comment: ohh thanks @Enzo, I get it now but the program still doesn't record the number of deaths, escapes and drowns at the very end?

Comment: It works perfectly now thanks @Enzo, but when I run the program it sometimes gives me a debug error, saying "Run-time Check Failure #2-S" any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Also for some reason, the result is either all deaths or all drowns (over 100 runs), do I have a problem with "escape" code or is it just a slim chance that the mouse escapes?

Answer (score -1):

There are some problems: you said the program should run a couple of times, but actually it runs just once. Worst of all, when the mouse reach the cat, the bridge, or drown, the program exits with:

```
return 0;
```

If you want to run it twice (or as many times as you want), you should put a loop like

```
for (int a = 0;a < 2;a++)
```

just after the variable declarations and before the initialization of the grid. This way, every time it runs the loop it reinitialize everything except your count variables.
Then, you should substitute the `return(0)` with a `break;`, so the inner loop exits every time something happens but the program still runs, and at the end you'll se the output print with your counts.

Oh, and I just saw you call `direction` with the third and fourth paarmeters fixed to "4".

...oh...and the mouse doesn't move at all. You should also update its location in the grid.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. how can I update the mouse's position? Also is the function that I am using correct? (I was hoping that the function would change the mouse's location)

Comment: Do you mean the function "direction"? That only check what's in the box the mouse wants to move, and it's fine. You should declare two new int variables with the mouse x and y position, and use them in all the places where you are using the fixed 4,4. Then at the end of the loop just update the grid position where the mouse is with a 0, change the mouse x (or y) value, reupdate the grid with a 1.